# FILESTREAM waits

Tags: windows, sql-server, filestream

I'm using a FILESTREAM enabled database that is hosted on SQL Server 2008 Standard Ed on a Windows 2003 server and am seeing some long waits of types PREEMPTIVE_OS_%.  Specifically, PREEMPTIVE_OS_GETFILESIZE when executing GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT().  I'm wondering if anyone can shed some light on what the PREEMPTIVE_OS_% wait types for FILESTREAM operations are.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Do you have any anti-virus software that might be attempting real-time scans on the files and delaying SQL Server from opening them quickly? That's the first thing that springs to mind.

Comment: thanks for the response ... anti-virus software isn't installed on this host.  have you worked with filestream in a production environment?  if so, what has the experience been for you?  So far, it's been a mixed bag from my perspective.

Comment: I've not had the opportunity to work with filestream storage much in production yet. There's very little documentation for those new wait types, oddly. At this point, you might consider running Process Monitor on the server and watching the filesystem activity within your filestream storage location to look for anything funny happening.